# Is it considered bad practice to pass various parameters of data when using delegation

Tags: ios, swift, parameter-passing, delegation, message-passing

I'm using the delegation pattern to pass data from one `viewController` to another `viewController`. I'm currently passing eight (8) parameters which I think are too many so, I was wondering if this is considered bad practice.

If this is considered bad practice, what would be a possible solution to pass various parameters of data between `viewControllers`?

```
protocol UserInputViewControllerDelegate {
    func messageData(make: String, model:String, engine:String, hasSunRoof: Bool, color:String, price:String, condition:ConditionType,  transmission:TransmissionType)
}
class UserInputViewController: UIViewController{
   // code

   func enter() {

         // send data to the delegate
        self.delegate?.messageData(inputMake.text!, model:inputModel.text!, engine:inputEngine.text!, hasSunRoof: self.hasSunRoof, color:inputColor.text!, price:inputPrice.text!, condition:conditionType,  transmission:transmissionType)
        closeView()

    }
}
```

Comment: would it make sense to combine these parameters into a model object and just pass that object ? assuming there is a relation between the data

Comment: you can pass this data as array .

Comment: There's nothing wrong with passing parameters via delegation. It's not like they're global or static.

Comment: That being said, using storyboards, I usually pass data from VC to VC using segues. Used to do it all the time using Obj-C, pretty sure it's comparable in Swift.

Comment: @KKRocks - I never tought I could have array with multiple types but it looks like you can, I just tested it, Thanks.

Comment: @ApolloSoftware I do too, but passing data back to the original VC I don't think is possible with segues.

Comment: I dont think theres anything wrong with passing all these parameters. All this data appears to be related so it makes sense to combine them into a model object to pass. If another param wanted to be added, you would have to change 3 places rather than just 1 change if the parameters were encapsulated in an object

Comment: @JoshHamet - Your are right, this maybe my best option. Thanks a lot for the suggestion.

Comment: Yeah, they are unidirectional unfortunately. You can do it during push, but pop I believe doesn't let you pass it back seamlessly. I've heard of people unwinding segues and passing via that route, or prepareForSegue.